# Flutter location package help : I would like to extract the co ordinates proved by the user into separate var/string or double

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter, dart, location

Can some one tell me how can i extract the latitude and longitude for
the below code?
I am using the location package from pub.dev to
get the users current location.
With the mentioned code i get both.
How ever I am trying to separate them in to var/strings/double.
So that i can use them else where.
here is the code.

```
Future<void> _getCurrentUserLocation () async {
final locData = await Location().getLocation();
print(locData.latitude)
print(locData.longitude)
```

just want to extra the values in (locData.latitude) & (locData.longitude) in a separate var/string or double.

Thanks Guys,
Steven

Comment: Not sure I follow your problem? What is the problem with: `double latitude = locData.latitude;`?

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out. the successful code to get the co ordinates in separate Strings is:

```
String _latitudeNew = '';
String _longitudeNew = '';

Future<void> _getCurrentUserLocation () async {
final locData = await Location().getLocation();
setState(() {
_latitudeNew = '${locData.latitude}';
_longitudeNew = '${locData.longitude}';
```

});

Thanks :)